# clustering map (North, Centre, South) in R

Tags: r, clustering

I am looking for a method to partition map in 3 groups (North, Centre, South) like this:
[image]
how to do this in R please

[stations.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucvck7irar4tmwl/stations.txt?dl=0)

Code :

```
Al <- shapefile("DZA_adm/DZA_adm0.shp")

# read in ascii file, and assign column names
x <- read.table('E:/cluster/stations.txt', sep=";")
names(x) <- c('long', 'lat')

# subset original object, return only x,y cols
y <- data.frame(x[,1:2])
#coordinates(y) <- ~long + lat
# simple plot of x,y data
plot(y, pch=4)
plot(Al,add=TRUE)
```

Partition the map above I done manually, looking for a way to do this automatically ,Which (modified) clustering algorithm will be appropriated for such task? (I work with R)?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include more details?  1. What is a card?  2. How did you arrive at the map you posted?  3? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you try to cluster your points by latitude you can explicitly divide them (to subsets or just add an attribute) depending on the value of the latitude.

Assuming coprdinates are in `Lat` and `Lon` columns

```
stations['clustres'] <- NA
stations$clusters [stations$Lat > n] <- 'North' 
stations$clusters [n > stations$Lat >= n1] <- 'Center'
stations$clusters [n1 < stations$Lat] <- 'South'
```

This will get your points assigned to clusters.

If you really need it you can create convex hulls or alfa-convex hulls ([CRAN package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphahull/index.html)). Though there could be gaps or overlaps between polygons after this.

I highly doubt that there is clustering procedure available to divide your points and щгедшту еруь the way you draw it.

Comment: thanks..look here please  I created a new discussion http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124677/how-to-separate-each-cluster-as-several-geographic-adjecent-areas-in-r